# Azure B2C - Use Predicates or Regexes for password validation

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

When validating user passwords to make sure they are complex enough when creating an account through an Azure B2C custom policy, is it preferable to use Regexes, or Predicates?

The default custom policy we've downloaded from Microsoft uses Regexes, which does the job. But would it be better to change the policy file to use Predicates instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's recommended to use the Predicates. The Predicates has better user experience and much more flexible to configure. Yep, the starter pack still use the Regex, but we advice customers to use the Predicates. See the [Configure password complexity using custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-password-complexity) doc for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD B2C by default uses `Strong` passwords. You can configure the password complexity rules like min,max length, character set/class for [bult in user flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-password-complexity).
Using the [Custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-password-complexity) we will have lot more freedom to configure the password complexity with Regular expression(regex) or by Predicate validation.

Regular expression and Predicate can be used restrict or set rules on the user input. There are some issue by using regex where you can over come with Predicate like the error message that we display for user input validation is scoped for the entire regex.
But by using Predicate validation you can define a collection of rules and can specify the error message that apply to different rule/rule groups which will help in communicating where users data entry is failing.

We recommend Predicates over Regex, but its upto you on choosing based on the password complexity you are building.